# [sql]wordpress custom post_type get overriden

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am having problems with my custom post type (quote) for my wordpress theme [WPF](https://github.com/MekZii/WPF/). The version on github has the custom post type in functions.php, but I have moved that to a plugin (wpf quote). I also added a custom widget.

The problem:
My main query doesnt include the custom post type "quote" (wish is fine, this is intended). The quote post type can be reached by going to: [domain]/quote/. This works fine and on this page the widget also works fine. But it goes wrong on a none-quote page (like on the homepage). The widget show the "content" and 2 meta values. The 2 meta values are not showing on a none-quote page.

I looked at the query and so I added `echo '<pre>'; print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']->request); echo '</pre>';` to my plugin.

On a quote-page:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'quote' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5`

On a none-quote-page:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5`

The only difference is `wp_posts.post_type = 'quote'` versus `wp_posts.post_type = 'post'`.

So the first one (quote) is the right one. I dont understand why it's changing back to post on a none-quote page. This is my widget() function within my WP_Widget-child:

```
<?php
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? '' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $read_more = $instance['read_more'];

    echo $before_widget;

    if (!empty($title)) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;

    $quotes = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_type' => 'quote'));

    if (count($quotes) > 0) {

        foreach($quotes as $post) {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($quotes); echo '</pre>';
            setup_postdata($post);
            // print the quote
            wpf_quote_print();
        }

        if (!empty($read_more)) {
            printf('<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>', esc_url(home_url()) . '/quote/', __('Read more quotes', 'wpf_quote'));
        }

    } else {
        echo '<p>' . __('There are no quotes yet', 'wpf_quote') . '</p>';
    }
    echo $after_widget;
}
?>
```

The function that's being called within the foreach is:

```
<?php
function wpf_quote_print() {
    // get the meta value's
    $quote_meta = get_post_custom();

    // first check if 'source_is_url' and 'quote_source' are not empty and prints the source as url. Else print source within parentheses.
    if (!empty($quote_meta['source_is_url'][0]) and !empty($quote_meta['quote_source'][0])) {
        $cite = '<cite><a href="' . $quote_meta['quote_source'][0] . '">' . $quote_meta['person'][0] . '</a></cite>';
    } else {
        $cite = '<cite>' . $quote_meta['person'][0];
        if (!empty($quote_meta['quote_source'][0])) $cite .= ' (' . $quote_meta['quote_source'][0] . ')';
        $cite .= '</cite>';
    }
    // print the html
    echo '<blockquote>' . get_the_content() . $cite . '</blockquote>';
}

?>
```

So why does wp change my query while I explicitly tell it to retrieve post with the type of quote? I think if I solve this then it will solve the problem I have now with not getting any meta values.

If it's easier I can fork my current work on github (I am gona fork it anyways to WPF when it's fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using a new WP_Query instead of get_posts(). Still dont know why it's not doing what I want with get_posts(). Later today I will place the hole thing on [github WPF](https://github.com/MekZii/WPF/).